# How do i convert nan values inside an numpy.ndarray to str type?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have my X_train which is type numpy.ndarray. Inside X_train i have few nan elements which are of type float. I don't want to remove them. Instead i want to convert them to str type.
How do i do it?
For eg- X_train[0]= 'fell victim two scam operation run involved making deposit total amount usd chase bank account fraudulent investment firm'

```
for i in X_train:
    if type(i)==float:
        print(i)
output-
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
```

Comment: So need `X_train = X_train.astype(str)` ?

Comment: What is this array's `dtype`?